# Ext.Net textEditor #{ character

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ext.net

I tired Ext.net textEditor and HtmlEditor. Have a problem.

Can't set value on Text properties. I try the following code

```
txtBody.Text = "#{dynamicBody}"

htmlEditor.Text = "${dynamicSQL}"

Replaced after render on 

txtBody.Text = Ext.Get("dynamicBody")

htmlEditor.Text = Ext.Get("dynamicSQL)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want token expansion, you should disable it in your `global.asax`, under `Application_start()` for example.

```
TokenUtils.Settings.Disable = true;
```

source: 
https://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?15965-Place-holder-with-a-format-parameter_name&p=92632&viewfull=1#post92632